# How to set write protection to all page in memory that a process is using?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-14.04

I want to write a function that set write protection to all page in Virtual memory. I that moment, I do like that:

```
mm = task->mm;
spin_lock(&mm->page_table_lock);

for (vma = mm->mmap ; vma ; vma = vma->vm_next) {   //loop for all vmas
  vma->vm_flags, (int) vma->vm_flags & VM_WRITE);                                           
  addr = vma->vm_start;
  vma->vm_flags &= ~VM_WRITE;       
  while(addr < vma->vm_end){ //loop for each page
     pgd = pgd_offset(mm, addr);
     if (pgd_none(*pgd)) { addr += PAGE_SIZE; continue; }       
     pud = pud_offset(pgd, addr);
     if (pud_none(*pud)) { addr += PAGE_SIZE; continue; }
     pmd = pmd_offset(pud, addr);
     if (pmd_none(*pmd)) { addr += PAGE_SIZE; continue; }
     pte = pte_offset_map(pmd, addr);
     if (pte_present(*pte)){
        *pte = pte_wrprotect(*pte);         
     } 
spin_unlock(&mm->page_table_lock);  
...........
```

I work on Ubuntu 14.04 (Kernel 3.13). My program work in kernel level.

But it just set write protection to a part of memory, it does't set write protection to all page that process is using.

Somebody can help me, please!

Comment: Why you think its not all pages and only part of memory?

Comment: Because in another process, I try to write to some pages of the memory of this process, in some of them the the SIGSEGV is occurred. in some of them it was not.

Comment: How are you writing into the virtual memory space of process A from process B?

Comment: @helloworld2008 You are only changing the mappings for one process (in that code anyway). Other processes will have their own virtual mappings (to the same underlying physical pages). So whatever VM changes you make for one process do not automatically translate to another process.

Comment: @Gil Hamilton and Alan Au: From process A, I scan all process that are running, and looking for the process that contain pid of process A. The code look like: `for_each_process(t)
   if (t->pid == b_pid) task = t;`
And from task, I get VM of B process.

Comment: It still isn't clear to me exactly what you're trying to do. But I suggest taking a look at the CONFIG_MEM_SOFT_DIRTY configuration option in recent kernels. If it doesn't actually do what you're wanting, it might at least provide a model for you to examine.